# Connection between cell phones using Android

Tags: android, sqlite, connection

Currently, I am working in a project which consist in a game, in a trivia with questions to be exact, and the idea is that the game can be multi player. I have the application ready and a data base in SQL Lite where I store the questions and the answers. The unique problem is that I can not do the connection between cell phones. In other words, I want that the second player lost immediately if the first player answer the question before the second player, but each player will be playing in one cell phone.

Comment: You don't want SQLite, you want something like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database).

Comment: So, with Firebase I can establish a connection between the cell phones?

Comment: You could have a central server where you could set up a rest api. The clients (our apps on the phones) would update a database on the central server.

Comment: You cannot directly connect; you communicate via writes to a shared, synced database.

Comment: Thank you for this information, I didn't have any idea. Now, I will search more information about Firebase.

Comment: Use [WiFi](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) or [Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html).